# My 2006 Pontiac Torrent main fuse box caught fire

Tags: pontiac, torrent

Put it out before there were flames and unplugged everything . Replaced the fuse box now passenger headlight won't go out and tail lights won't go out. Dash lights flicker and radio flickers i have interior over head lights but it still won't start . Any idea where to start or what might be wrong. This car is my lifelines and I can't afford a mechanic ... Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: You clearly have one or more short circuits in the wiring.  A lot of the wiring will need to be replaced.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sorry to say, but we won't have an easy or quick fix for you. The big question here is why was there a fire in the first place. Shorting electrical components can cause a fire. If you have not resolved what caused the fire in the first place, you are fighting a losing battle. Also, it sounds like some of the wire harness connected to the fuse box has been damaged by the fire's heat, causing short circuits. You need to take this to a mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

Short circuit, loose connections and feeding high-consumption loads without proper fuses are perhaps the main causes of fuse box/wires smoke, melting and if out stopped, fire that can consume a car very quickly and up to its bones. You would need patience and a kind of CSI inspection to determine which wire or fuse in the fuse box was the principal cause of the the damage.

For instance, if a headlight's fuse was loose and because the headlights are a high-consumption load if they use ordinary bulbs, it is enough to heat the fuse socket with all it implies: heat will melt the socket, moving the wire connections, probably make them touch each other or touch ground, etc.

If you take a good look to the wires and the fuse box you may be able to find which was the principal one, because it will look more damaged than the other. This is a highly empiric way to check for what happened tho.

If you replaced the fuse box and some of the stuff are not working, you perhaps wrongly connected the feeding wires to these. Again, patience and check one by one. It is a good time also to check that all fuses, all connections and ground are properly tight (a loose one may reproduce your previous problem, also justifies your flickering radio). Check every connection, one by one, also put high-consumption loads to work and touch its fuse and wires to sense it they are getting hot. Heat is no good, if you can sense that then that part of the circuit is damaged, wire touching ground, wire having more than one load attached somewhere, etc.

*However if you got such heat to almost get a fire, changing the fuse box will not suffice: you may need also to change the wires harness, not all of them but perhaps the ones involved and I would specifically change the one to the key.*

Try to find your car's mechanics manual or its Haynes book, and use the electrics diagram to assist you.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the advice I can't afford a new car or mechanic so giving up isn't an option . i will just have to keep trying

Comment: Also the wire harnesses were replaced as well

Comment: replacing the harness without checking the source of the problem may not be good...if the problem was other than the harness itself, the new one would be cooked again.

Comment: I have the sane problem. Everything works proudly on my torrent after replacing the fuse box and harnesses. The only thing not working properly is the ignition system. I turn the key and get nothing at all. I have checked all connections with a multimeter and an getting 12 volts to main fuse box. However testing power wire going into ignition switch and no power to ignition switch. Could this possibly be the bcm.

Comment: Disconnect the wire from fuse box to the ignition key, disconnect it from the ignition key too, make a wire with connectors and temporally supply 12V to the ignition key. This should be a thick wire, like the original you will see there. Check if ignition works then. With that test you can define that the original wire is damaged and maybe it was the issue's source. IF that's the case, the solution may be installing that test wire permanently, together with the harness but connected to the fuse box or an inline fuse if the fuse socket for this is damaged.

Comment: Also: check the contacts in the ignition key module. If you got heat, one or more of the poles connectors there may have got moved away because the heat would melt the plastic they are inserted in. I had a problem with it once: the main contact pole moved just a mm away because heat...enough to put the whole system down. I replaced it after taking care of the issue's source (in my case, overrated headlight bulbs...car used 50/90w and they installed 100/130w!!!)